# C Programming: Singular to plural nouns

Tags: c

my program here is supposed to

Write a program that takes nouns and forms their plurals on the basis of thee rules:

1. If noun ends in “y”, remove the “y” and add “ies”.
2. If noun ends in “s”, “c”, “ch”, or “sh”, add “es” .
3. In all other cases, just add “s”.

Print each noun and its plural.

It works fine, when I enter word such as dairy it prints dairies, but it loops and prints dairieseseseseseseseseseseses...etcetc. I was hoping this is a quick fix that I can't find and somebody can help me with it!

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>



#define max_word 20



/* prototypes */
void pluralize (char word[]);


int main (void)
{ 
  char noun[max_word];   /* stores temporary word entered by user */

  printf("Enter a noun in singular form: ");
  scanf("%s", noun);

  while (strcmp(noun, "done") != 0)
 {
    pluralize (noun);
    printf("The plural form is %s\n", noun);
 }

  return;
}

void pluralize (char word[])
{
  int length;
  char noun;
  length=1;
  length = strlen(word);

   if (word[length - 1] == 'y') 
 {   word[length - 1] = 'i';
     word[length] = 'e';
    word[length + 1] = 's';
    word[length + 2] = '\0';  
  }


  /* if word ends in "s" "ch" or "sh" add "es" */

 else if (word[length - 1] == 's' ||
    (word[length - 2] == 'c' && word[length - 1] == 'h') ||
    (word[length - 2] == 's' && word[length - 1] == 'h'))
  {  strcat(word, "es");
  }

  else
 {   strcat(word, "s");

    printf("New word is: ", &noun);
} 
return;
}
```

Comment: If you don't want it to loop, why does your main have a while loop?

Comment: that's a damn good question. seemed to have fixed it. thanks haha

Comment: It's not the problem you're looking for, but `main` returns an `int`. Make sure your `return` statement at the end of the block reflects this.

Comment: You need a loop if you're going to pluralize several words in a single session. The fact that you're checking for "done" suggests that this is the case.

Comment: I think your instructor forgot "x" in the second rule... ;-)

Comment: You have a buffer overflow when you make the new words longer than the original.  You need to allocate larger variables to accomodate the new additions.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that you want the program to terminate if the user enters the text `done`.  If so, you need to fix your loop:

```
for (;;) 
{
    printf("Enter a noun in singular form: ");
    scanf("%s", noun);

    if ((strcmp(noun, "done") == 0)
        break;

    pluralize (noun);
    printf("The plural form is %s\n", noun);
}
```

The current version will loop until `pluralize()` sets the string to `done`, which will never happen.

As a side note, you should be using `strncmp()` and `strncat()` to avoid a potential buffer overflow.  This is not too important in this kind of code, but if you're ever writing something that faces an untrusted user, you could be opening yourself up to a serious security vulnerability by using `strcmp()` and `strcat()`.